# Why (T) explicit cast not work in a <T>function

Tags: c#

I want to use `N<T>` instead of use `T?`
But I can't use`(T)` explicit cast  in a function with`<T>`

Why `(T)` explicit cast not work? how to fix it.

Why `(1 is int?) == true`.
How could I make my struct N has the same power.
Make `(1 is N <int> ) == true`

```
using System;
public struct N<T> where T : struct
{
    public T value;
    public bool HasValue;
    public static implicit operator N<T>(T value)=> new N<T> { value = value };
    public static explicit operator T(N<T> value)=> value.value;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        N<int> a;
        //System.Int32 can't cast to N`1[System.Int32]
        //error or not work
        a = To<N<int>>(2);

        //success     but not elegance
        a = To<N<int>>((N<int>)2);
        
        //success
        int? b = To<int?>(2);
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static T To<T>( object o) 
    {
        //return (T)o;         //System.InvalidCastException
        if (o is T) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("success");
            return (T)o; 
        }
        if (o is Func<T>)        {            return (o as Func<T>).Invoke();        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(o.GetType() + " can't cast to " + typeof(T));
        return default;
    }
}
```

Comment: `1 is N<int>` will *never* be true; the semantics of `is` don't permit that, not with all the implicit conversions in the world. `Nullable<T>` is subject to special rules in the language that your type isn't privy to and you cannot duplicate its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

A cast can mean a bunch of different things:

- identity-preserving cast (upcast, downcast, interface cast)
- boxing/unboxing
- numeric conversion
- call to user-defined conversion operator

Every time the compiler sees cast syntax, it has to look at the type to figure out which one.  With generics, the compiler has only the generic constraints to use to decide which one.

`To<T>` has no constraints, so the compiler has to interpret the cast in a way that works with all types... every type inherits from `object`, so it chooses the cast from `object` to be a downcast.  When you actually call the function, the input is a "boxed `int`* and the output type is *`N<int>`* and the downcast fails.